# Reference file from RStudio's working directory in Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I have a chuck in a Sweave document, where I'd like to source a file from RStudio's working directory. I edit these files using both Ubuntu and Windows, so I'd like to avoid explicitly writing out the name of the working directory in the sweave document.

When I try the code below. It just says that it can't find the file.

```
<<>>=
source("file.R")
@
```

Comment: When you say RStudio's working directory, what do you mean? The working directory in RStudio is generally whatever directory the file you double-clicked to open RStudio is. If you opened it via a menu or something similar, I believe it's the home directory.

Comment: R on Windows will accept forward slashes in path names, so at least don't let that aspect of your situation keep you from hardcoding the file paths.

Comment: The working directory is set by the RStudio project I'm using. The Sweave folder is in a subfolder called Sweave, and the R files are in a subfolder called R.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I'm still having trouble due to the difference between "~/Dropbox/" and "C:/user/me/Dropbox"

Comment: Do `path.expand()` or `normalizePath()` help at all?